Context is lost when tab is switched - React js, supabase
I have auth context that uses supabase api to detect auth state changes and handle user data and session in context. user data is loaded from database.
The problem is that when i switch tab and return to app, context (or user filed in context) seems to be lost and i have to refresh page to get it back.
Here is the code:
import { Session } from "@supabase/supabase-js";
import {
  useContext,
  useState,
  useEffect,
  createContext,
  ReactNode,
  FC,
} from "react";
import { supabaseClient } from "../supabaseClient";
import { User } from "../model/User";

// Define the interface for the context value
interface AuthContextType {
  session: Session | null;
  user: User | null;
  loading: boolean;
  setUser: (user: User) => void;
  signOut: () => void;
}

// Create the context with the defined type
const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextType>({
  session: null,
  user: null,
  loading: true,
  setUser: (user: User) => {},
  signOut: () => {},
});

// Define the props for the AuthProvider component
interface AuthProviderProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

// AuthProvider component
export const AuthProvider: FC<AuthProviderProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);
  const [session, setSession] = useState<Session | null>(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [initialLoad, setInitialLoad] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const setData = async () => {
      try {
        const {
          data: { session },
          error,
        } = await supabaseClient.auth.getSession();
        if (error) throw error;

        setSession(session);
        const sessionUser = session?.user;

        if (sessionUser) {
          // Fetch additional user data from the database
          const { data: userData, error: userError } = await supabaseClient
            .from("users")
            .select("*")
            .eq("id", sessionUser.id)
            .single();
          if (userError) throw userError;

          setUser({
            ...userData,
            email: sessionUser.email,
            role: sessionUser.role,
          });
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching user data:", error);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
        setInitialLoad(false);
      }
    };

    setData();

    const { data: listener } = supabaseClient.auth.onAuthStateChange(
      (_event, session) => {
        setSession(session);
        setUser(user ?? null);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    );

    return () => {
      listener?.subscription.unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  const value = {
    session,
    user,
    loading: loading || initialLoad,
    setUser: (user: User) => setUser(user),
    signOut: async () => {
      await supabaseClient.auth.signOut();
      setUser(null);
      setSession(null);
    },
  };

  // Use a provider to pass down the value
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
      {!loading && !initialLoad && children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

// Export the useAuth hook
export const useAuth = () => {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
};


I tried to save user data in local storage but it doesnt work (either i can not log out and it takes over the session or it doesnt save and load user)
